# How do I get cmake to find python3.9 instead of python3.10 on ubuntu22.04

Tags: python, cmake, python-3.9, ubuntu-22.04

Python3.10 breaks a lot of python scripts and it's the default on Ubuntu22.04.  I have a cmake script that keeps on picking up Python3.10 when I have Python3.9 installed (even when python3.9 is set as default on my system) how do I make cmake find python3.9 using command line options? Location would be /usr/bin/python3.9 or /usr/bin/python

Comment: Use `which` and point to that in the Makefile?

Comment: `sudo update-aliternatives --install /usr/bin/python python /usr/bin/python3.9 9`?

Comment: when you ran ./configure did you pass the /usr to --prefix=? After as @Osyotr mentioned you can update your alternative and set 3.9 to be default

Comment: why not just tell cmake to call `python3.9`? seeing as you specifically don't want anything higher than 3.9. doing something like `update-alternatives` is an invasive change to your system. doing something like fiddling with the PATH variable is tricky to get cross-platform and python3.9 could be installed in different places on different machines.

Answer (score 2):

How did you search for python in your CMakeLists.txt ?

If using the built-in module [FindPython3](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/FindPython3.html) you should be able to control the python used using `-DPython3_ROOT_DIR="your_python3.9_install_dir"`

Comment: Thanks a lot for pointing to the docs. How do you actually provide the directory for the python *interpreter*? I thought they are all in `/usr/bin` or the like.