# Found Python3.9, but I want to use python3.10

Tags: python, linux, cmake

Due to some breakage in another project that didn't run in python3.10 I had to install python 3.9 on my ubuntu 22.04 machine. Because python3.9 is not available in the package repositories, I cloned the github repository and ran configure, make and make install, which installed python3.9 into `/usr/local/bin`.

Now I am trying to compile pivy against python3.10, which is my default python version. But I think CMake picks up python3.9 now by default. I tried reinstalling python with `sudo apt install python3 --reinstall`, but that didn't help. I also tried to replace all occurrences of python3.9 with python3.10 in the files generated by cmake, but that also gave an output of `-- Found Python: /usr/local/bin/python3.9 (found version "3.9.13") found components: Interpreter Development Development.Module Development.Embed` on the first line of make.

I have found a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73042989/how-do-i-get-cmake-to-find-python3-9-instead-of-python3-10-on-ubuntu22-04), but it doesn't exactly match what I want. Firstly, I don't know what the installation directory for the apt python version is. the python binary is in `/usr/bin/`, but so could be the 3.9 version (it's in /usr/local/bin/ right now). Secondly, I would like to have that as the default.

I have tried removing the softlink to python3.9-config in `/usr/local/bin/python3-config`
and running python3-config now runs the one in `/usr/bin/python3-config`, which points to the 3.10 version. However running cmake now says it can't find python at all. Even after clearing the cmake cache and reseting the repository.

```
CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-3.22/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:230 (message):
  Could NOT find Python (missing: Python_EXECUTABLE Python_INCLUDE_DIRS
  Python_LIBRARIES Interpreter Development Development.Module
  Development.Embed)
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /usr/share/cmake-3.22/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:594 (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)
  /usr/share/cmake-3.22/Modules/FindPython.cmake:561 (find_package_handle_standard_args)
  CMakeLists.txt:17 (find_package)
```

I have tried creating a new softlink to the correct python3-config in `/usr/local/bin`, but that gave the same cmake error.

`apt-file search FindPython` revealed that that file is in the cmake-data package, which I reinstalled. That also didn't work.

I don't know what to do now. How can I make cmake find the correct python version by default? There are no entries for python or python3 in update-alternatives. I noticed there are a lot more python executables in `/usr/local/bin/`, for example `python-argcomplete-tcsh`, is that a problem if I want to use 3.10 by default?

I was able to get around the issue for now using

```
cmake .. -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -DPython_EXECUTABLE=/usr/bin/python3.10 -DPython_INCLUDE_DIRS=/usr/include/python3.10/
```

But that's only a stopgap measure. I would like a proper solution that makes FindPython work properly again.

Comment: I'd strongly suggest against messing around with the system Python lest it break some core libraries/programs. Instead, consider using an environment manager such as Anaconda/Miniconda, which will let you run multiple Python environments of different versions in parallel without affecting each other or system Python

Comment: python is a giant mess of versions and incompatibilites. somehow even my virtualenv broke on me and it now wants to use python from some environment I deleted ages ago and throws me an error. I might just ditch this whole system and install parrotos or something.